# Regex assertions extrange behavior

Tags: php, regex, assertion

I am using regex in PHP to eliminate italic html orphan labels from a text line (living the text untouched if the labels are paired), using regex assertions, and I am being successful to do so when I want to eliminate <i> that is not followed by </i> later in the same line using this sentence:

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/(.*)<i>(?!.*<\/i>)(.*)/', "$1$2$3", $buffer);
```

but, when I try to do the same for </i> labels not preceded by <i> in the same line, using:

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/(.*)(?<!<i>.*)<\/i>(.*)/', "$1$2$3", $buffer);
```

It returns null (I think meaning syntax error). I know that the problem is the "*" after "?<!<i>." because if I use:

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/(.*)(?<!<i>.)<\/i>(.*)/', "$1$2$3", $buffer);
```

and I test with an string with only one character between <i> and </i> (like "TEST<i>1</i>WORKS") it goes fine, but of course, this is no useful, as I do not know how much characters will be between <i> and </i> in operations. I am assuming that the **negative lookahead assertion** of the first command should have a symmetric behaviour than the **negative lookbehind assertion** of the second, but it seems not to be the case.

Can someone wise in regex tell me how to circumvallate this issue?

Thanks to all and best regards.

Comment: [Famously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/740553): don't use regex to parse HTML Use an actual DOM parser instead, like php-html-parser or simplehtmldom or the like.

Comment: Assertions are of no use here. You'd typically use a [`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) *alternative* for cases to ignore.

Comment: Well, the text to be parsed is not HTML. I used" \<i>" and "\</i>", but I could have used #startt# #end#. I only use those two labels to delimitate an italic styling. Then I think (*SKIP) and (*FAIL) are not available in my environment.

Comment: According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php: "The contents of a lookbehind assertion are restricted such that all the strings it matches must have a fixed length." Since your pattern does not have a fixed length, this approach can't work. You may have to just iterate your string and look for matching symbol pairs, or if they may be nested, parse it into a symbol stack and look for mismatches?

Comment: Thank you Don R. That reference is what I needed